# Why Bitlocker with TPM requires fastboot in BIOS

Tags: bitlocker, tpm

HP Probook 445 G7

When I turn off fastboot in BIOS under Advanced > Boot Options bitlocker stops working. It goes in Bitlocker recovery after I enter the password (extended alphanumeric pin with TPM 2.0) and then fails with 8007139f.
It works fine after I re-enable fastboot in BIOS.

What's the connection between fastboot and bitlocker/TPM?

Comment: This is most likely a problem with this specific model. Because in the first place not every UEFI firmware supports fast boot.

Comment: @DanielB, thinking about it I guess it has to do with fast boot enabled when I added added the key to TPM and when I disable it now it's considered a configuration change and TPM would refuse to work with the changed configuration.

Comment: That’s how TPM key protection works, yes. It is bound to Platform Configuration Registers which contain various information. However, Fast Boot or not is not a security-relevant change.

Comment: If it were just a PCR change, Windows would still boot normally after the recovery key prompt (and automatically reseal the key). Boot failure is likely caused by something else.

Comment: @user1686, in my setup there's no recovery key protector. Tried disabling and removing the TPMandPIN Bitlocker protector, disabling fast boot, re-adding and enabling the protector again and it now works with both fastboot disabled and enabled, so not sure what's the deal here.

Comment: "What's the connection between fastboot and bitlocker/TPM?" - There really isn't a connection, other then the fact, configuration changes require the BitLocker Recovery code.  Why are you trying to disable fastboot?